# Are these the correct equations for the set of following distribution questions?

Tags: combinatorics

1. distributing identical balls into a set of distinct boxes empty allowed:

n = number of distinct boxes, m = number of identical balls

$\binom{n+m-1}{m}$ so 5 balls, 3 boxes would result in $\binom{7}{5}$

2. distributing identical balls into a set of distinct boxes with no empty boxes

$\binom{m-1}{n-1}$

3. set of distinct balls into a set of distinct boxes

T(m,n)

Comment: What is T(m,n) ? If it means $n^m$, all ok.

Comment: If ball ordering inside each box does not matter